# New mastodon instance does not show any search results

Tags: mastodon

I did setup a new mastodon instance by following their official [documentation](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/admin/prerequisites/).
Cloud provider: AWS
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
mastodon version: tag v3.5.5

Everything looks good. I can sign up and publish toots. However, the instance seems isolated from the rest of the world.
I do not get any results when I search for something in the search text area.
[image: No search results]

Also, I don't see anything when I click on "Home", "Notifications", "Explore", "Local", "Federated" tabs except for my own toots.
[image: Empty Home]
[image: Empty Notifications]
[image: Empty Federated]

I checked the logs for each events I have mentioned above, but couldn't find any errors

```
Nov 19 18:59:42 mastodon bundle[962]: [2f300833-5315-46c0-a896-476795ededd3] method=GET path=/api/v1/announcements format=html controller=Api::V1::AnnouncementsController action=index status=200 duration=8.95 view=0.81 db=2.90
Nov 19 18:59:54 mastodon node[904]: verb f63957b3-a3a1-4c02-bd4e-effab9a79982 Starting stream from timeline:public:local for 109367375149862625
Nov 19 18:59:54 mastodon node[904]: verb Subscribe timeline:public:local
Nov 19 18:59:54 mastodon bundle[960]: [ba690cc1-f2f9-46dd-a566-914e7125f875] method=GET path=/api/v1/timelines/public format=html controller=Api::V1::Timelines::PublicController action=show status=200 duration=26.52 view=5.64 db=4.51
Nov 19 18:59:56 mastodon node[904]: verb f63957b3-a3a1-4c02-bd4e-effab9a79982 Ending stream from timeline:public:local for 109367375149862625
Nov 19 18:59:56 mastodon node[904]: verb Unsubscribe timeline:public:local
Nov 19 18:59:56 mastodon node[904]: verb f63957b3-a3a1-4c02-bd4e-effab9a79982 Starting stream from timeline:public:remote:media for 109367375149862625
Nov 19 18:59:56 mastodon node[904]: verb Subscribe timeline:public:remote:media
Nov 19 18:59:56 mastodon bundle[962]: [258f251b-74b1-4108-8df4-1ac83046f829] method=GET path=/api/v1/timelines/public format=html controller=Api::V1::Timelines::PublicController action=show status=200 duration=14.09 view=0.38 db=2.86
Nov 19 19:00:00 mastodon bundle[519]: 2022-11-19T19:00:00.102Z pid=519 tid=2aeb INFO: queueing Scheduler::InstanceRefreshScheduler (instance_refresh_scheduler)
Nov 19 19:00:00 mastodon bundle[519]: 2022-11-19T19:00:00.103Z pid=519 tid=2ajv class=Scheduler::InstanceRefreshScheduler jid=de4112a35ea1c3ba20f43230 INFO: start
Nov 19 19:00:00 mastodon bundle[519]: 2022-11-19T19:00:00.182Z pid=519 tid=2ajv class=Scheduler::InstanceRefreshScheduler jid=de4112a35ea1c3ba20f43230 elapsed=0.079 INFO: done
```

I tried restarting the server entirely after the installation. Even so, the server seems isolated.